# PHP curl returns (35): SSL connect error

Tags: php, ssl, curl

Im trying to visit the following page using php curl 7.35.0 using the following code:

```
    $this->ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3000);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3600);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://asp.reflexion.net/login');
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $content  = curl_exec($this->ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($this->ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($errno    = curl_errno($this->ch))
    {
        $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
        echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    echo "http code: " . $httpCode . "<br>";
    echo "content: " . $content;
```

Which returns the following:

cURL error (35): SSL connect error

http code: 0
content:

Did anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: That error code means a Time out. Your network connection to that host is most likely faulty.
There might be a problem with the SSL libraries used by the curl bindings in PHP.

Comment: How do I troubleshoot this? it looks like I cant access that page with no problems using Chrome.

Comment: _"Did anyone run into this problem before?"_ - [let's check, shall we?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cURL+error+%2835%29%3A+SSL+connect+error)

Answer (score 3):

Adding

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 3);
```

solve my issue.

Comment: If you scroll down to **CURLOPT_SSLVERSION** at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) you can see: 
**Setting it to 2 or 3 is very dangerous given the known vulnerabilities in SSLv2 and SSLv3.**

Answer (score 2):

usually, this is an firewall issue.
SSL connection is banned by network administrator.

Comment: can you pls explain a bit more how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:
**`yum update nss`**

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/642203

Comment: Centos 6.4 here, this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue as well.

Our environment

PHP 5.3.3
libcurl 7.19.7-46
google-api-php-client 1.1.5

Deep within the Google API Client Curl code, httpd would die inside the curl_exec().  After changing CURLOPT_SSLVERSION  from 1 to 3, all is well :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Note:
Your best bet is to not set this and let it use the default. Setting it to 2 or 3 is very dangerous given the known vulnerabilities in SSLv2 and SSLv3.